# Как изменить размер изображения?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Есть задача: при нажатии кнопки должно открываться изображение с выбранными параметрами. Как это реализовать на c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap(string path,int height, int width);
||
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap(int height, int width);